# Does chronoboost shorten warp gate's cooldown time?

Tags: starcraft-2

Does chronoboost shorten a warp gate's cooldown time? Does it affect warp-in time at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it affects cooldown time.

No, it doesn't affect warp in time.

Comment: You might want to add this as an extra source.
http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Chrono_Boost

Answer (score 2):

If you use the chrono boost on a warp gate, the cool-down time of the warp gate decreases (or the cool-down speed increases by 20%). However, the actual warping in time taken for each unit is unaffected.